# What is stack ? arrayStack ? arrayQueue ? stackQueue ? how are they different in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

I'm just learning all the basic stuff about Stack in my Data Structure C++ class. However, it's getting a bit confused between them. Can anyone tell me whats the def. of arrayStack and arrayQueue, stackQueue and their differences ? and the text book is not really helpful at all.

Comment: Which text book? Which language?

Comment: The text book is called C++ Plus Data Structures

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974922/what-is-the-basic-difference-between-stack-and-queue

Comment: I could understand the different between stack and queue. Stack is LIFO, and Queue is FIFO; but what are arraystack and arrayqueue ?

Comment: Where have you got the words "arraystack" and "arrayqueue" from? Given http://staff.ppu.edu/ysalah/C++Plus%20DataStructures.pdf and a search I don't think they are in the book.

Comment: it's from here http://opendatastructures.org/ods-cpp.pdf
Besides the book, we need to read a lot of material that were supplement by the instructor

Comment: There's no such thing as stackQueue even in the link you provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> Firstly you need to understand the fundamentals, lets take a ride thorough the basics again.
>
> We begin with stack empty:
>
> -----
> stack
> Now, let's perform Push(stack, A), giving:
>
> -----
> | A |  <-- top
> -----
> stack
> Again, another push operation, Push(stack, B), giving:
>
> -----
> | B |  <-- top
> -----
> | A |
> -----
> stack
> ```
>
> Stacks
>
> The conceptual picture of a stack is something like this:
>
> ```
> Now let's remove an item, letter = Pop(stack), giving:
>
> -----              -----
> | A |  <-- top     | B |
> -----              -----
> stack              letter
> And finally, one more addition, Push(stack, C), giving:
>
> -----
> | C |  <-- top
> -----
> | A |
> -----
> stack
> You'll notice that the stack enforces a certain order to the use of its contents, i.e., the Last thing In is the First thing Out. Thus,
> ```
>
> we say that a stack enforces LIFO order.
>
> ```
> Now we can see one of the uses of a stack...To reverse the order of a set of objects.
>
>
> Like a stack, a queue usually holds things of the same type. We usually draw queues horizontally. Here's a queue of characters with 3
> ```
>
> elements:
>
> ```
> queue
> -------------
> | a | b | c |
> -------------
>   ^       ^
>   |       |
> front    rear
>
>
> Queues are useful because they produce a certain order in which the contents of the queue are used. Let's see what order that is by
> ```
>
> looking at a queue of characters. Now, what would a particular
>   sequence of Enter and Deletes do to this queue:
>
> ```
> queue
> -------------
> | a | b | c |
> -------------
>   ^       ^
>   |       |
> front    rear
> Now, Enter(queue, 'd')...
>
> queue
> -----------------
> | a | b | c | d |
> -----------------
>   ^           ^
>   |           |
> front        rear
> Now, ch = Delete(queue)...
>
> queue           ch
> -------------   -----
> | b | c | d |   | a |
> -------------   -----
>   ^       ^
>   |       |
> front    rear
> ```

Comment: Thanks kotAPI. What is about Array Stack and Array Queue, and Stack Queue data structure ? are they array or stack or queue ?
http://opendatastructures.org/ods-cpp.pdf

Comment: Array stack- implementing stack using arrays in programming.
Array Queue- implementing queue using arrays in programming.

Comment: @kotAPI, It looks like you have quoted this answer from another answer. It would be nice if you mention where you copied this from.

Answer (score 1):

Both the stack and the queue are data structures that grow naturally as you add elements.

- In a **stack**, elements are added (pushed) to the one side of the stack and then retrieved (popped) from the same side of the stack. In other words, the last element you insert is the first element you can retrieve. This type of data structure is known as LIFO (Last In, First Out).
- In a **queue**, elements are added to the back of the queue and retrieved from the front. In other words, the first element you insert is the first element you can retrieve. This type is known as FIFO (First In, First Out).

In various languages (not specifically C++ or its libraries), there are various ways that naturally growing data structures can be implemented. One such way is by keeping a simple **internal array**: Elements are stored in the array and the add/remove operations take care of growing or shrinking that internal array, without bothering you. Usually, when a structure is called *ArraySomething*, it *should* mean something along these lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I got it now

Answer (score 1):

An `ArrayStack` is intern based on an array.

The most important difference of them all is, that a `Stack` is based on the `LIFO (Last In First Out)` system, so you add your elements to the top `(push)` and if you want to take an element form the stack `(pop)`, you also take it from the top. If you add a few elements:

```
stack.push(1), stack.push(2), stack.push(3)
```

and then pop one off:

```
stack.pop() //returns 3
```

A `Queue` is based on the `FIFO (First In First Out)` system, so you add elements on the "back" of the queue and you get your elements from the "front" of the queue. This means if you add three elements:

```
queue.add(1), queue.add(2), queue.add(3)
```

and then want to get an element from the queue:

```
queue.get() //returns 1
```

ArrayStack, ArrayQueue means, that they are implemented as an array. And a StackQueue is a combination of both. You could get your elements from the front and from the back.

Comment: I have never heard of an ArrayStack before. Is this a guess, or have you read the same book?

Comment: This just means, that the implementation behind the stack or the queue is an array, not a linked list or something like that.

Comment: so if it is an ArrayStack, it still has to follow the rule LIFO, and if it is a ArrayQueue, it based on the FIFO ?

Comment: Yes, so this could be a class, that uses an array to store its data, but only allows you to to input and get your data following the FIFO or LIFO rules.

Answer (score 1):

An [array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure) is a way to organize data (and its storage allocations), whereas [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) and [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29) are policies to `insert`, `remove` or `access` data.

Different `policies` can be combined with the `organizations` to construct different data structures according to your needs.

For example:

- Stack using an array
- Queue using an array
- Stack using a linked list
- Tree using an array etc.

Comment: I found that your answer is the most easy one to understand ;)

Answer (score 0):

C++ Standard doesn't say anything about the structures you've mentioned (apart from `std::stack` container adapter). Hence, you have to read the chapter again.

*Most probably* you can also throw the book away, too, and start using standard containers instead.

Comment: That's real helpful for the understanding of the basic differences between stack and queue.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar That would be an answer for a completely different question than OP asked.